# How to make Play! framework dist command adding some files/folders to the final package?

Tags: deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wanted the Play! framework `dist` command to add some folders and files to the final zip file. They are needed for the application to work.

Is there a magic `project/Build.scala` configuration to make it possible? I couldn't find it in the Play! [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTSettings).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Play uses [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/), which supports the inclusion of arbitrary files by adding them to the mappings:

```
mappings in Universal ++=
  (baseDirectory.value / "scripts" * "*" get) map
    (x => x -> ("scripts/" + x.getName))
```

The syntax assumes Play 2.2.x.

Comment: At last :) This question was long lost.

Comment: @Roland can you post the code to copy nested sub-directories and its contents.

Comment: See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html: `(baseDirectory.value / "scripts" ***).get pair relativeTo(baseDirectory.value)`

Comment: @Roland Kuhn: Your provided link is unfortunatly dead. Can you maybe adjust?

Comment: This is one of the more useful answers I've come across. Thanks for sharing @Roland

Comment: For sbt 1.3.4, 
`import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport.NativePackagerHelper._`

`mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "resources")`

Answer (score 5):

My Play application was not including template files (in app/views/) in the distributable, and I added them with this in Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here   
  playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "app/views"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the `dist` [source code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L174), I think it is not possible.

But you can use the `play clean compile stage` command to package the app and its dependencies (from [doc](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Production)):

> This cleans and compiles your application, retrieves the required
>   dependencies and copies them to the target/staged directory. It also
>   creates a target/start script that runs the Play server.

Then you'll have to write your own script to add your directories and build a zip.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure since which Play version this has been supported, but [Play! 2.5 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy) suggests that you can add any arbitrary files you want to package under a 'dist' folder (at the root of the project). I'm using SBT native packager to build my project into an RPM and this work perfectly out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just tested this and it appears to work. Albeit the editor Atom seems not to like (as in hides) a root folder called Dist so unsure if that conflicts with something else (in MY environment...) (Update: My bad - was just a folder in .gitignore for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

I can bet that I won't satisfy you, but maybe you won't waste your time for searching. As **Nico** pointed there's no such possibility, the fastest approach you can use is to write a bash script (or *.bat file) to do that.

I spent an hour for looking the solution... and 15 minutes for writing script which unzips, modifies, zips and send a file to the remote destination, so consider if it will not be better option for you as well.